# Python: How configure 'Try' and 'Except' in for statsmodels RuntimeWarning when 'divide by zero' is encountered

Tags: python, statistics, try-catch, data-science, warnings

I'm writing a small programm for data exploration: I have data of about 3-4 different groups (with subgroups, so probably about 10-20 different pairings) with about 50+ tests (float point number values) each. My goal is to graph and statistically analyze this data. The idea is not to have publication-ready statistics/graphs but to get an initial overview over the data.

I've successfully implemented the normality testing via scipy.shapiro and depending on that either a RM-anova via statsmodels or a Friedman-test via scipy, both followed by tukeyhsd post-hoc testing via statsmodels.
Then a combined boxplot/swarmplot and friedmann/RManova + post-hoc tables are saved as a figure to a folder.
This works fine for most of the data/tests, but I get a few errors like this:

```
site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_py.py:7933: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in
double_scalars chisq = (12.0 / (k*n*(k+1)) * ssbn - 3*n*(k+1)) / c
```

or this

```
statsmodels\sandbox\stats\multicomp.py:1300: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
st_range = np.abs(meandiffs) / std_pairs #studentized range statistic
```

I am also missing a few graphs, the number of which corresponds directly to the number of these error messages. Therefore, I assume that the program does not export a graph if this error occurs but skips to the next iteration.

As such I would like to implement some sort of try/except rule where if this error occurs, the data is still graphed (the iteration not ended prematurely).
Thank you in advance for any help!

Sidenote: I also get the warning

```
scipy\stats\_morestats.py:1758: UserWarning: Input data for shapiro has range zero. The results may not be accurate.
  warnings.warn("Input data for shapiro has range zero. The results "
```

for some Data, but this does not stop the current iteration (and I would like to not go to "except" because of this)

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it: Going through my code I found out that I wrote down one of my iterator tests twice so I was calculating the number of graphs/figures I excepted as output wrong.
Apparently the number of Runtime-Warning == "missing" graphs was just a coincidence.
Sorry guys!